# ORDER BY last column

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have this:

```
SELECT
    NONEMPTY(
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
    )
    *
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,
    ORDER(
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].MEMBERS
        ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        ,BDESC) 
     on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

What is the most efficient way of ordering descending by the last date column - this should be dynamic so that it still works when we go over month end.

Comment: By "efficient", do you mean "fast performing" or "easy to write the MDX", i. e. "efficient for Analysis Services" or "efficient for the developer"?

Comment: @FrankPl always fast performing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
ORDER(
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].MEMBERS
        ,([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
          ,Tail([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]).Item(0).Item(0)
         )
        ,BDESC)
```

and assume that the added term `Tail([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]).Item(0).Item(0)` can be calculated by Analysis Services just checking the time dimension, and does not need any dynamic context, and hence should be fast.

Comment: +1 pretty similar to what I have done - although instead of arguments 2 and 3 in your solution I have them as a tuple: is that the same?

Comment: @whytheq Actually, that is how it should be. I corrected my answer. `Order` does not accept four arguments. That is what happens if you just put the code into the answer without running it against a real server.

Comment: Cool - do you not have the Ad Wks cube Frank?

Comment: @whytheq Yes, I have it. But the answer seemed so easy to me that I did not want to open Management Studio to answer it. Maybe I should have done that...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an expression which is independent of the content of the columns, you can use:

```
ORDER([Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].MEMBERS
      ,Tail(Axis(0)).item(0)
      ,BDESC)
```

Comment: But the `Axis` function can make a query slow, especially if combined with some other MDX features. And the question was asking for the fastest performing way, not for the easiest to write/maintain MDX. In the latter case, your answer would have been correct.